# SQL query to get time diff from closest (in time) previous db entry

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database

I have 2 db tables to deal with an issue tracking system (like Zendesk or Jira): a `tickets` (parent table) and a `messages` (child table, storing each message of a ticket). Something like this:

`tickets` table:

```
id
created_at
```

`messages` table:

```
id
created_at
ticket_id
text
source (could be either 'company' or 'client')
```

I would like to craft a SQL query which would yield ticket messages where each row involves a 'company' message along with the time delay since the last 'client' message. By "time delay" I mean:

`created_at` from 'company' message MINUS `created_at` from previous 'client' message

Note that it is possible to have several 'company' or 'client' messages in a row.

So if ticket (with id 4528) has those messages (in chronological order):

```
- 'client' message (id 1)
- 'company' message (id 2)
- 'client' message (id 3)
- 'company' message (id 4)
- 'company' message (id 5)
```

I would expect the SQL query to yield something like:

| ticket id | message id | Time diff since previous 'client' message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4528 | 2 | time diff between 2 and 1 |
| 4528 | 4 | time diff between 4 and 3 |
| 4528 | 5 | time diff between 5 and 3 |

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I have removed the multiple RDBMS tags. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69638506/edit) and tag one that correspond to your environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4f1d406253df3139f959dd39dffdaa81)

Just `join` the `company` rows with applicable `client` rows having prior `created_at` values. Then assigned a `row_number` to these `client` rows per `company` in reverse time order. Pick `n = 1` to obtain the most recent prior `client` row for each `company` row.

We can add `ticket_id` to the `PARTITION BY` clause to handle multiple tickets.

**The SQL:**

```
WITH cte1 (id, ticket_id, text, ts, client_id, ts2, n, dt) AS (
        SELECT m1.id, m1.ticket_id, m1.text, m1.created_at
             , m2.id AS last_client_id, m2.created_at
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m1.id, m1.ticket_id ORDER BY m2.id DESC) AS n
             , m1.created_at - m2.created_at AS dt
          FROM      messages AS m1
          LEFT JOIN messages AS m2
            ON m1.ticket_id = m2.ticket_id
           AND m2.source = 'client'
           AND m2.created_at < m1.created_at
         WHERE m1.source = 'company'
     )
SELECT * FROM cte1 WHERE n = 1
;
```

I didn't notice the `MySQL` tag on the original question, just the `postgresql` tag.  The structure of the SQL is basically the same for both, with a little adjustment for the time difference calculation.

**Here's something for recent versions of MariaDB/MySQL too ([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9d34868bfae0d0aec522bddbe5f85fe)):**

```
WITH cte1 (id, ticket_id, text, ts, client_id, ts2, n, dt) AS (
        SELECT m1.id, m1.ticket_id, m1.text, m1.created_at
             , m2.id AS last_client_id, m2.created_at
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m1.id, m1.ticket_id ORDER BY m2.id DESC) AS n
             , ABS(timestampdiff(minute, m1.created_at, m2.created_at)) AS dt
          FROM      messages AS m1
          LEFT JOIN messages AS m2
            ON m1.ticket_id = m2.ticket_id
           AND m2.source = 'client'
           AND m2.id < m1.id
         WHERE m1.source = 'company'
     )
SELECT * FROM cte1 WHERE n = 1
;
```

Older versions of MySQL or Maria won't have `WITH clause` or `Window Function` support.  It's still doable.

**The setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
  id          int
, created_at  timestamp
, ticket_id   int
, text        varchar(30)
, source      varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO messages (id, ticket_id, source, text, created_at) VALUES
  (1, 1234, 'client' , 'message 01', current_timestamp + INTERVAL '+1 HOUR')
, (2, 1234, 'company', 'message 02', current_timestamp + INTERVAL '+2 HOUR')
, (3, 1234, 'client' , 'message 03', current_timestamp + INTERVAL '+3 HOUR')
, (4, 1234, 'company', 'message 04', current_timestamp + INTERVAL '+4 HOUR')
, (5, 1234, 'company', 'message 05', current_timestamp + INTERVAL '+5 HOUR')
;
```

**The INTERVAL syntax is slightly different for MySQL/MariaDB:**

```
INSERT INTO messages (id, ticket_id, source, text, created_at) VALUES
  (1, 1234, 'client' , 'message 01', current_timestamp + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
, (2, 1234, 'company', 'message 02', current_timestamp + INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
, (3, 1234, 'client' , 'message 03', current_timestamp + INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
, (4, 1234, 'company', 'message 04', current_timestamp + INTERVAL 4 HOUR)
, (5, 1234, 'company', 'message 05', current_timestamp + INTERVAL 5 HOUR)
;
```